# iOS - Load the download page in app store?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [On the iPhone, how can you cause a URL to display an entry in the App Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835759/on-the-iphone-how-can-you-cause-a-url-to-display-an-entry-in-the-app-store)

How can I open an external download page for an application through an iOS app?

There are duplicates of this question, but the answers don't really help so here I am asking again.

NOTE: I don't want to open the "itunes" app, I want to open "App Store"

Comment: Non of the answers in that thread worked for me, and most of them instruct how to open "itunes" not "app store"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I get to the "App Store" app to open.  Note: this only works on a real device, it does not work on the simulator.  iOS intercepts that itunes URL and opens the App Store app instead:

```
#define APP_STORE_URL @"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id123456789?mt=8"

NSURL* redirectToURL = [NSURL URLWithString:APP_STORE_URL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:redirectToURL];
```

Of course, replace the id number with your app's id number.  I got this from the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835759/on-the-iphone-how-can-you-cause-a-url-to-display-an-entry-in-the-app-store/3835796#3835796) and it does work.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I used to do it.

```
NSString *storeURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=%@&;amp;amp;amp;amp;mt=8",yourAppStoreID];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:storeURLString]];
```

You will need to determine what your AppStore ID is by selecting "Copy Link" in iTunes and removing the "id" prefix from the unique id in the URL.